# Get Array Variables from inside of a Session

Tags: php, arrays, session

Hi I have a session $_SESSION['pdf_quote'] when i view all values in the session I get all the results correctly but i have one value which displays The value of `$_SESSION['product_arr']` is 'Array' I have tried to printr the values of that array but all i get is a blank page...

```
 foreach($_SESSION['pdf_quote']['product_arr'] as $key=>$value)
 {
    // and print out the values
     echo 'The value of $_SESSION['."'".$key."'".'] is '."'".$value."'".' <br />';
 }
```

i've tried everything to try and access the data in the array but for the life of me I can't figure it out.

print_r displays

```
Array ( 
 [FoodDelivery] => Array ( 
    [FDelivery_Order] => Array ( ) 
    [FDelivery_Captcha] =>     EAHVZS) 
 [pdf_quote] => Array ( 
   [id] => 42 
   [location_id] => 3 
   [type] => pickup 
   [status] => pending 
   [payment_method] => none 
   [is_paid] => 0 
   [txn_id] => 
   [processed_on] => 
   [price_subtotal] => 6300.00 
   [price_delivery] => 0.00 
   [price_total] => 6300.00 
   [voucher_code] => 
   [created] => 2013-10-15 08:48:16 
   [p_dt] => 2013-10-19 08:00:00 
   [d_address_1] => 
   [d_address_2] => 
   [d_country_id] => 
   [d_state] => 
   [d_city] => 
   [d_zip] => 
   [d_notes] => 
   [d_dt] => 
   [c_name] => ewqe 
   [c_email] => weqw@ewewe.com 
   [c_phone] => 3232323 
   [c_address_1] => ferwewe 
   [c_address_2] => 
   [c_notes] => 
   [c_country] => 
   [c_state] => www 
   [c_city] => 
   [c_zip] => 2122 
   [cc_type] => 
   [cc_num] => 
   [cc_code] => 
   [cc_exp] => 
   [product_arr] => Array ( 
     [0] => Array ( 
       [extra_arr] => Array ( ) ) ) ) )
```

i've tried to loop the array without success im not sure what code i need to use to be able to see the variables stored in the `product_arr` array.

Comment: That's weird. Maybe, the error is somewhere else? print_r must work

Comment: A blank page usually means something's wrong. Add `ini_set('display_errors',1); 
 error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the top of your script and see if it outputs any error messages.

Comment: whats the output of var_dump($_SESSION['pdf_quote']['product_arr']); , can u post it ?

Comment: If the value is another array, then echo won't work.  Would you mind to print_r($_SESSION); and paste here?

Comment: var_dump is array(1) { [0]=> array(1) { ["extra_arr"]=> array(0) { } } }

Comment: As you can see, the product_arr has another array, so echo won't work here.  In this case you check if the content is_array, if it's true the you must do another foreach/loop and retrieve the values.

Comment: how do i code to do another foreach loop?

Comment: I wonder if: echo 'The value of $_SESSION[' is causing an issue - have you tried escaping the $?

Comment: can someone help me code up a foreach loop to get the values out?

Comment: after turning on error reporting im getting Array to string conversion

Comment: do i need to explode the array to get the variables?

Comment: You don't [explode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) arrays, you [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) them _(hint: the little blue words in this comment are links)_.

Comment: when i try to implode $products = implode(", ",$_SESSION['pdf_quote']);;

echo $products

i get array to string conversion warning

Comment: i just figured that the items are in the database!